# What is By in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.id(//[@id='kishr']));
```

What is By above?

Is this `class` ,`reference` or `object` ?

Answer (score 2):

`By` is an `abstract class`

and

`id` is a `static method`, so is `linkText`, `partialLinkText`, `name`, `tagName`, `xpath`, `className`, `cssSelector` in `By abstract class`.

Since it's a class level methods, you don't really need an object to call these methods.

`By.id` or `By.xpath` etc. should suffice.

[Official docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html)

Answer (score 0):

By is an abstract class its provides a way to various search criteria's to locate the locator, it provides 8 method for 8 locator stategies,All 8 method are static so call them we have to use class name,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).